# How to Convert Long format Date to Short format Date with Type DateTime in C#

Tags: c#

I want convert long dateTime to only date in C#. and both in dateTime type

```
DateTime creationDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime shortDate = creeationDate.Date;
```

Comment: Your `shortDate` will have zero time (midnight).

Comment: This code doesn't compile. creEationDate is not creationDate. Probably this is the problem. Otherwise this is working.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Have you tried formatting the date? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Fix `creeationDate` then update your question.

Comment: Consider using NodaTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DateTime` is a struct, which always has -- as the name suggests -- date and time components. You cannot remove the time and there is, as far as I know, no built-in date-only type in .NET (maybe there is in some 3rd party libraries).

You have already discovered the `Date` property of `DateTime` which returns an new `DateTime` with the time components set to `00:00:00.000`.

If you only need to output your current date you must apply some formatting on the `DateTime`

```
DateTime creationDate = DateTime.Now;
string shortDate = creatationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); //or whatever formatting you need.
```

If you need calculations on your date, but want to ignore the time component, you could initialize your date accordingly, as you have done in your code.

```
DateTime creationDate = DateTime.Now.Date; //sets time component to 00:00
DateTime otherDate = new DateTime(2016, 11, 2, 0,0,0);  //also initializies with time 00:00
int diff = (int)(otherDate-creationDate).TotalDays; //number of days between the two dates
```